# Registry Editing: How to calculate DWord Hex Values

Tags: registry, hex, windows-ce, dword

I'm trying to make some registry edits and I'm not sure I understand how specific dword values are calculated.

Here are two examples:

```
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Volume]
 "Volume"=dword:0xFFFFFFFF ; 0=off, 0xFFFFFFFF=maximum

 "Refresh"=dword:493E0 ; every 5 minutes
```

For the volume, how would I calculate what the range of options are if 0xFFFFFFFF is the max? And for "Refresh", if 493E0 is every 5 minutes, how do I figure out what every minute, or every day or every hour would be?

This is a Motorola Symbol MK4000 WinCE 5.0 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the windows calculator into scientific mode, you can convert between HEX and regular DECIMAL easily.

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=HextoDecConversion

EDIT:
The number 0x493E0 is 300000, which I imagine is the number of MILLISECONDS, divide that by 1000 to get the number of seconds (300), divide that by 60 to get the number of minutes (5).

Comment: So 493E0 converts to 300,000 == number of milliseconds in 5 minutes. Sweet. On the other hand, 0xFFFFFFFF = 4294967295 (not sure how this translates to a volume) - thoughts? I'm guessing half this would be 50% volume.

Comment: the number 0xFFFFFFFF is the highest number you can store in an unsigned 32bit number, which I imagine is why they set it as such.  That limit itself is to prevent buffer overflows on int32 types, and is probably NOT the actual logical limit (as it's probably much lower).

Answer (score 2):

Volume is splt in 2.  [The low word is left and the high word is right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908146.aspx).  0xffff on a channel corresponds to 100% or "max".  50% is 0x7fff and so on.  Remember that is also rarely linear, so 50% volume doesn't mean 50% as loud.

**EDIT**

To clarify a bit further, the volume is split into two channels.  I'll assume that you want the same volume on each.

The general formula is `[left value] | ([right value << 16])`

Here are examples:

For 100%, a value of 0xFFFF on both channels is what you want.
`Value = 0xFFFFFFFF == 0xFFFF | (0xFFFF << 16)`

For 50%, a value of 0x7FFF on both channels (0xffff / 2) is what you want.
`Value = 0x7FFF7FFF == 0x7FFF | (0x7FFF << 16)`

For 25%, a value of 0x3FFF on both channels (0x7fff / 2) is what you want.
`Value = 0x3FFF3FFF == 0x3FFF | (0x3FFF << 16)`

Comment: Hmm. This is a bit confusing, especially after reading the MSDN article.